# Problema com nextLine() após nextInt() em um Loop

Tags: java

Eu tenho esse código para remover de uma `ArrayList`, e um `while` para verificar se o usuário quer continuar removendo elementos. Mas quando o valor de remover é verdadeiro a lógica "pula" a próxima pergunta (*Deseja continuar?*).

```
package AList;

import java.util.*;

public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> agenda = new ArrayList<>();

        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int pos = 0;
        String opcao;
        agenda.add("Cachorro, 12345");
        agenda.add("Doido, 54321");

        int n = agenda.size(); //pega o tamanho
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.printf("Agenda pos %d = %s\n", i, agenda.get(i));
        }

        do {
            System.out.println("Digite o elemento para remover: ");

            try {
                pos = entrada.nextInt();
                agenda.remove(pos);
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Erro " + e);
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                entrada.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Erro: " + e);
            }

            System.out.println("Deseja continuar? ");
            opcao = entrada.nextLine();
        } while (!opcao.equals("n"));

        int i = 0;
        for (String contatos : agenda) {
            System.out.printf("Agenda pos %d: %s", i, contatos);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Como faço para conseguir capturar a entrada do usuário na segunda pergunta?

Comment: Poderia detalhar melhor o problema? Não consegui entender sua descrição.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que o método `nextInt()` não consome a quebra de linha digitada pelo usuário. Você precisa descartá-la antes de chamar `nextLine()` novamente:

```
pos = entrada.nextInt();
entrada.nextLine(); // Descarta quebra de linha
agenda.remove(pos);
```

---

**Fonte**: [SOen - Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045/664577)