# Problemas com FOR em um exercicio simples em Java

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Então, estou resolvendo um exercício simples em Java, que está me causando uma dor de cabeça. O exercício proposto é fazer um programa para ler nome, idade e altura de N pessoas, conforme. Depois, mostrar na tela a altura média das pessoas, e mostrar também a porcentagem de pessoas com menos de 16 anos, bem como os nomes dessas pessoas caso houver. Eu consegui fazer tudo, mas estou preso na parte onde devo mostrar o nome das pessoas com menos de 16 anos, acredito que o problema esteja no último FOR.

Classe Data:

```
package entities;

public class Data {
    private String name;
    private double altura;
    private int idade;
    
    public Data(String name, double altura, int idade) {
        this.name = name;
        this.altura = altura;
        this.idade = idade;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getAltura() {
        return altura;
    }

    public void setAltura(double altura) {
        this.altura = altura;
    }

    public int getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }

    public void setIdade(int idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
    }
    
}
```

---

Classe Programm:

```
package application;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

import entities.Data;

public class Programm {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Quantas pessoas serão digitadas? ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        Data[] vect = new Data[n];
        
        
        for(int i = 0; i < vect.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Dados da " + (i+1) + "a pessoa:");
            System.out.print("Nome: ");
            String name = sc.nextLine();
            sc.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Idade: ");
            int idade = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Altura: ");
            double altura = sc.nextDouble();
            vect[i] = new Data(name, altura, idade);
        }
        
        double sumAlt = 0.0;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < vect.length; i++) {
            sumAlt += vect[i].getAltura();
        }
        
        System.out.println();
        double avgAlt = sumAlt / vect.length;
        System.out.printf("Altura media: %.2f", avgAlt);
        sc.nextLine();
        double avgIdade = 0.0; 
        
        for(int i = 0; i < vect.length; i++) {
            if(vect[i].getIdade() < 16) {
                avgIdade += 1;
            }
        }
        
        avgIdade = avgIdade / vect.length * 100;
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Pessoas com menos de 16 anos: " + avgIdade);
        sc.nextLine();
        
        
        
        for(int i = 0; i < vect.length; i++) {
            if(vect[i].getIdade() < 16) {
                System.out.println(vect[i].getName());
            }
        }
        
        sc.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -2):

No seu código teve o problema do método nextInt() que não consome a quebra de linha digitada pelo usuário, dessa forma, a primeira variável String name é pulada, indo diretamente para a pergunta da idade.

Sendo assim, no primeiro for abaixo da pergunta sobre o nome da pessoa ficaria:

```
String name = sc.nextLine();
       name = sc.nextLine();
```

e não:

```
String name = sc.nextLine();
              sc.nextLine();
```

Colocar apenas sc.nextLine(); vai fazer com que sua variável nome continue vazia.

No final do seu código, acredito que vc queria colocar um println e nao um Scanner, dessa forma:

```
avgIdade = avgIdade / vect.length * 100;
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Pessoas com menos de 16 anos: " + avgIdade);
        System.out.println();
```

e não dessa:

```
avgIdade = avgIdade / vect.length * 100;
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Pessoas com menos de 16 anos: " + avgIdade);
        sc.nextLine();
```

Fazendo essas alterações o código rodou corretamente, abaixo o código completo corrigido e espero ter ajudado.

```
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Programm {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Quantas pessoas serão digitadas? ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        Data[] vect = new Data[n];
        
        
        for(int i = 0; i < vect.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Dados da " + (i+1) + "a pessoa:");
            System.out.print("Nome: ");
            String name = sc.nextLine();
            name = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Idade: ");
            int idade = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Altura: ");
            double altura = sc.nextDouble();
            vect[i] = new Data(name, altura, idade);
        }
        
        double sumAlt = 0.0;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < vect.length; i++) {
            sumAlt += vect[i].getAltura();
        }
        
        System.out.println();
        double avgAlt = sumAlt / vect.length;
        System.out.printf("Altura media: %.2f", avgAlt);
        sc.nextLine();
        double avgIdade = 0.0; 
        
        for(int i = 0; i < vect.length; i++) {
            if(vect[i].getIdade() < 16) {
                avgIdade += 1;
            }
        }
        
        avgIdade = avgIdade / vect.length * 100;
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Pessoas com menos de 16 anos: " + avgIdade);
        System.out.println();
        
        
        
        for(int i = 0; i < vect.length; i++) {
            if(vect[i].getIdade() < 16) {
                System.out.println("Menor de 16: " + vect[i].getName());
            }
        }
        
        sc.close();
    }

}
```

**Fonte:** [Problema com nextLine() após nextInt() em um Loop](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/159444/problema-com-nextline-ap%C3%B3s-nextint-em-um-loop)

Answer (score -2):

Outra forma de fazer é usando *streams* e seus *collectors*:

```java
        List<Data> list = Arrays.asList(vect);

        final var alturaMedia = list.stream().collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(Data::getAltura));
        final var nomes = list.stream().filter(d -> d.getIdade() < 16).map(Data::getName)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        final var porcentagem = (double) nomes.size() / list.size();
```